# How to compute the derivative of the magnitude of a vector?

Tags: vector-calculus, calculus-and-analysis

Mathematically we can say the following

$$ \frac{d}{d\vec{x}}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}|} = -\frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^3}.$$

However, in Mathematica, I perform the following `D[Abs[x]^(-1), x]` which outputs `-Abs'[x]/Abs[x]^2`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what you mean deriving scalar by vector? The closest assumption i can think about is d F[x]/d x = Grad[F, x], x={x1,x2,...,xn}

Comment: It's one of the examples of the help page for [Grad](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html?q=Grad).

Answer (score 1):

```
Quiet[xx = Table[x[[i]], {i, 1, 3}]];
D[1/Sqrt[Dot[xx, xx]], {xx, 1}]
```

Remark: The length of a vector in Mathematica is obtained by `Norm[x]`. `Abs` operates on each entry, thus `Abs[x]` is the vector of moduli.

Comment: I thought so however, when I use Norm I get results using Conjugates. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Yes, see above.